# MYSQL count only those students with number 1

Tags: mysql

i would like construct a query to count the number of student who don't have number 0.

assuming i have 2 tables

students
*student_id
*name

Number
*number_id
*student_id
*number

| Student 1 |
1
1
1
1
| Student 2 |
1
1
1
1
| Student 3 |
1
0
1
0

|Student 4 |
0
1
1
1

So the result should be. student without zero = 2
student with zero = 2

Comment: Please edit your question and do a better job of explaining what the data is.  What are the names of the columns?  What is the name of the table?  How many rows does a student have?

Comment: This is a very awkward, unconventional representation of the contents of a relational table. What is the table name? What are the column names? Is there a query that demonstrate anything being returned from the table?

Comment: can you show the columns too?

Comment: This question seriously makes no sense. If you could provide schema, that could help a lot.

Comment: done editing the question

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that your table has the following structure:

```
id | value
1  |   1
1  |   1
1  |   1
1  |   1
2  |   1
etc...

SELECT id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might return the specified result:

```
SELECT CONCAT('student without zero = '
            , ( SELECT SUM(1)
                  FROM ( SELECT t.`some_identifier`
                           FROM `sometable` t
                          GROUP BY t.`some_identifier`
                         HAVING SUM(IF(t.`some_col`=0,1,0)) = 0
                       )
              )
            , '\n'
            , 'student with zero = '
            , ( SELECT SUM(1)
                  FROM ( SELECT z.`some_identifier`
                           FROM `sometable` z
                          WHERE z.`some_col` = 0
                          GROUP BY z.`some_identifier`
                       )
              )
       ) AS `result`
```

Just replace `some_table` with the name of the table, `some_col` with the name of the column that contains the 1 and 0 values, and `some_identifier` with the column that contains the `Student 1`, `Student 2`, etc. values.

This should return a single row, something like this:

```
 result
 --------------------------------
 student without zero = 2
 student with zero = 2
```